# Can't read images from C:\ in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, image

I realize this is an edge case, but it seems that asp.net doesn't allow reading images from the root drive. To test this I wrote the following very simple application:

On the page I have:

```
<asp:Image ID="test" runat="server" />
```

In the code behind I have:

```
test.ImageUrl = @"C:\test\image.jpg";
test.AlternateText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test\text.txt");
```

Both files exist as you'd expect and have the correct permissions. When viewing the source of the page we get an img tag that looks like the following:

```
<img id="test" src="C:\test\image.jpg" alt="some text to read" style="border-width:0px;" />
```

When I run this in VS no image is displayed. If I copy the source, paste it into an html file and load it into a browser the image is displayed. Can anybody explain why this is?

Comment: Note: for the sake of argument, I do want to load this file from the user's hard drive, not the server's. In this specific case it's running in VS, from my computer so server and client are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser is preventing the images from being displayed. I created a static HTML page containing an  tag whose "src" pointed to an image on my local file system. If I open the HTML page locally, everything works as expected. However, when I hosted the static HTML page in a web server, it stopped working.

I ran ProcMon while loading the HTML page from the remote server, and the local file was accessed (some columns truncated for display purposes):

```
iexplore.exe    6376    QueryDirectory  C:\test.jpg SUCCESS test.jpg
iexplore.exe    6376    QueryOpen   C:\test.jpg SUCCESS 
iexplore.exe    6376    QueryDirectory  C:\test.jpg SUCCESS 
iexplore.exe    6376    CreateFile  C:\test.jpg SUCCESS
iexplore.exe    6376    ReadFile    C:\test.jpg SUCCESS
iexplore.exe    6376    CloseFile   C:\test.jpg SUCCESS
```

However, IE did not display the image. I repeated the test with Firefox. When accessing locally, the ProcMon results were the same. When accessing remotely, ProcMon didn't produce any output.

Answer (score 4):

The `src` of an `img` tag should rarely point to a file on your local disk. It should be an URI. Perhaps you'll have more success using the `file:///C|/test/image.jpg` syntax.

Comment: +1 This WILL work to display a file from the visitors local drive.

Comment: I tried this as well, but it didn't work. I could browse the file directly by requesting this file with my browser or when requesting through the HTML file, but it wouldn't load when asp.net requested it.

Comment: There may be some security sandboxing in your browser settings to prevent it.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the way you're assigning the img src.  By providing C:\test\image.jpg as the sourc you're instructing the BROWSER to get the image from the user's local drive rather than from the server's location.

All src directories/files should be specified using relative paths for your website.  For example:  If your homepage was located on your server at c:\www\homepage.aspx and you also had an images sub-directory located within the www directory then you'd want to specify your img src to be something like this:  `<img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="Image" />`

Answer (score 1):

I know that you said the permissions were correct, but double check and make sure the aspnet\aspnet_wp account has permissions to the file location. When you run an asp.net application it runs under this account. When you load an HTML file in your browser, it runs as you.

Comment: Yea, that was my first thought too. I even went so far as to give the "everyone" group full read/write access. That didn't help :(

Comment: The permissions actually don't matter as the browser is the one requesting it; so as long as the user has access, then it should display.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're feeding a "URL" into the `src` tag, and the browser treats it as such. When you open a file such as `C:\test.html` it is simply rendered by the web broswer and uses the local source as the starting URI, but when you load from another source, such as `http://localhost/test.html` then the file needs to be accessible through http, and `http://C:\test\image.jpg` is not a valid URL.

Comment: When I request `file:///C|/test/image.jpg` it doesn't work either, but that's instructing the browser that I want that file.

Comment: There may be some security sandboxing in your browser settings to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work properly if you use a url. Not sure what the difference there would be though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser security "feature".  The goal is to prevent malicious websites from accessing your local files, and causing them to either be executed or uploaded to the website without your knowledge.

In order to get past it I believe you will have to change your security zone to "local intranet", then drop the security down to pretty much allow everything.

Obviously this is only viable for machines you directly control.

Comment: Ah, this is what I was suspecting. So when I run in VS it's spinning up a light-weight web server the the browser is interpreting as a real server. When it's in an html page the browser realizes I loaded the page from my local machine and it sets the security zone appropriately. 

If this is the case, why can I load the text from a text file, but not an image?

Comment: Ah, silly me, as soon as I typed that, I realized where my mistake was. The text file is loaded in the context of the web server, which does have access to the files (both of them), but this control just adds whatever I type there into the src attribute of the tag, then it's up to the browser to decide what to do. At which point the text comes from the server, and the image is attempted to load from the local disk, which fails.

Answer (score 0):

The html code is invalid. It should not render in any browser, VS, firefox, IE or any other. In fact it does not in firefox.

Comment: Uh, you're talking about `<asp:Image>`? He's just using a server side component based MVC framework which generates HTML output.

Comment: the generated HTML code is invalid. As others responders have already correctly pointed out, the src attribute is not correctly coded.

Answer (score 0):

If You display images from C: drive or any local drive in a server side web application development. It will create conflict-ion from client drive if they are same file and folder name in client computer. That's why you Can't read images from C:\ in ASP.NET.

To read the images from local server drive first you will to create virtual directory for your local drive(C:\Gallery) then you can display images from folder.

example:

<
asp:Image Id="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Filename", "http,://localhost/ImageGallery/{0}") %>' Width="150px" Height="150px"  runat="server" />

please remove from http, like http
Shankar Chaurasia