# How to display images which is stored outside the folder?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to display images which is stored outside the root folder in asp.net 
like :

`Image1.ImagUrl="C:\temp\Images\img1.jpg"`

but it is not helpful for me. So Please help me.

Comment: What errors are your getting?  How is your web root and the folders/files below it secured?

Comment: refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130745/how-to-display-image-which-is-stored-in-local-drive   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981968/cant-read-images-from-c-in-asp-net

Comment: hey **@DWright** I am not getting any error, only image is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

The path you are supplying is not a URL. You need to supply the virtual path to the file, not the absolute (file system) path.

```
Image1.ImagUrl="~/Images/img1.jpg"
```

The browser is incapable of reading files on your local file system.

You can map a virtual directory to any directory on your file system so it has a virtual path. Let's say you want to make the physical directory `C:\temp\Images\` into a virtual directory called `/Images/` and you are using IIS 7.

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2. Under sites, navigate to the site you wish to place the virtual directory in.
3. Right click on the site node, and click "Add Virtual Directory...".
4. For the alias, type `Images`.
5. For the Physical Path, type `C:\temp\Images\`.
6. Click OK.

Now you can access your image through the virtual directory `/Images/img1.jpg`.

```
Image1.ImagUrl="~/Images/img1.jpg"
```

Comment: I do not want to use virtual path ,I want to display image from other folder means using physical path.

Comment: That makes no sense. For a web application you *must* use the virtual path. You can make paths outside of the root folder by configuring them as virtual folders.

Comment: hey @NightOwl888 would you give me the example for same ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Image1.ImagUrl=@"C:\temp\Images\img1.jpg"
```

put a @ before the path string